# Compact sets of metric spaces are closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am struggling with the idea that all compact subsets of a metric space are closed after reading chapter 2 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

The reason I am confused is that it seems unreasonable that a compact subset must be closed. If we were to take an open subset $K$ of a compact subset $Y$ in a metric space $X$, where $K$ is open relative to $X$, then every finite subcover of $Y$ would also be a finite subcover of $K$. But then, $K$ would be both compact and open in $X$, which contradicts the theorem that all compact subsets in $X$ are closed.

Could someone please explain to me why my reasoning is incorrect and how it is  that compact subsets of metric spaces must be closed?

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: In addition to what the answers have pointed out, it seems you are making the popular mistake of thinking that open and closed are opposites. They are not. A set can be open, closed, both, or neither.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with your reasoning is that $K$ may have an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ that does not arise from an open cover of $Y$, so that compactness of $Y$ doesn’t tell you anything about $\mathscr{U}$.

It’s easiest, I think, to prove the contrapositive: if $A\subseteq X$ is not closed, then $A$ is not compact. Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space, and suppose that $A\subseteq X$ is not closed. Then there is a point $p\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$U_n=\left\{x\in X:d(x,p)>\frac1n\right\}\;,$$ and show that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $A$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I understand it now.

Comment: @Evan: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sir  im not  getting what is the $(\operatorname{cl}A)?$

Comment: @jasmine: That’s one of the standard notations for the closure of $A$.

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot for this. This is very helpful. All this time, I'd been trying to prove it by taking $\delta=\inf\{d(p,x):x\in A\}$ and then getting a neighborhood around $p$ disjoint from $K$ (success for $\delta \gt 0$) but $\delta =0$ possibility was not giving any contradiction so the approach didn't work. This idea of considering this $\delta$ comes from seeing things in $\mathbb R^n$. Sir, any hint on how to proceed to contradict $\delta=0$?

Comment: @Koro: You will always have $\delta=0$ when $p\in\operatorname{cl}A\setminus A$, but the method that I suggested in the answer still works: $\bigcup_nU_n=X\setminus\{p\}\supset A$, so $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ really is an open cover of $A$, but $B\left(p,\frac1n\right)\cap U_n=\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and you can use this and the fact that $p\in\operatorname{cl}A$ to show that no finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $A$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $F$ be our compact set. Then take $x\in X\setminus F$. Because {$x$} and $F$ are compact ,then they have a distance,say $d$.And thus the open disk $D(x,\frac {d}{2})\subset X\setminus F$. So $X\setminus F$ is open and thus $F$ is closed.

Comment: What is $d$ precisely? It can't be $\inf\{d(x,f): f\in F\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate proof if you know that compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness:  suppose $Y$ is compact, and $x$ is a limit point of $Y$.  Let $(x_n) \subset Y$ with $x_n \to x \in X$ and for all $n$, $x_n \neq x$.  $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence  converging to some $y \in Y$ because $Y$ is compact.  But since the whole sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent and converges to $x$, $x=y$.  So $x_n \to y \in Y$.  $Y$ contains all its limit points. $Y$ is closed.